# How to search for files in a directory that matches multiple string strings

Tags: search, grep, find

m looking for a command or maybe a script to search for files that contains strings in multiple line and display the file names

example
in /var/tmp/ there are multiple files
each files will contain the following

file1:
John
2015Oct
foo
dell

file2:
Dave
2014Sept
samsung

file3:
John
2014Oct
dell

and so on

how can I find files that contain John and 2015 together ?

Answer (score 0):

In grep regex you may use `|` for OR. Just for example:

```
grep -rnw . -e "head"
```

It chooses all files recursive from current dir which contain word `head`.

```
grep -rnw . -e "head\|footer"
```

Same command but it chooses files with words `head` or `footer`.

Note: backslash needs for escaping. You also can use `egrep` without backslash in regex.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want, and you can keep chaining it through more pipes if you have more "and" constraints (files containing **x** and **y** and **z** and **...**):

```
grep -l "John" *.txt | xargs grep -l "2015"
```

**-l**: That's a lowercase L, meaning to list the names of files containing matches rather than the default line-by-line match output.

***.txt**: Obviously, replace this parameter with whatever you require for your file name list that you're looking through for your matches.

**xargs**: Calls grep with the specified parameters plus the file names piped in from the output of the preceding grep.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, both worked, however when it comes to a folder with thousands and thousands of files, i start getting argument too long error

grep -l  "150728" *  | xargs  grep -l "Chri"

-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long